# JavaScript code in PHP if acting oddly

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show a popover if a PHP session variable is set. That being 'emailEmpty' for the moment.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['emailEmpty']) && $_SESSION['emailEmpty'] == true): ?>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
   });
 </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

When I click the log in button and my password is empty the session variable 'emailEmpty' is set to true. But the popover does not show properly, it shows up like this. (The title of the popover is 'Warninggg'

[image: Screenshot]

```
<input type="email" id="emailPopover" name="email" data-placement="bottom" class="form-control required name" title="Warninggg" data-content="aasd" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="Email">
```

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here

Comment: @JohnConde irrelevant? I only want the popup to show if the session variable is true. So how is the PHP irrelevant?

Comment: It seems work, right? Your only problem is how the popup looks like. So it's entirely a frontend problem, the PHP works and is therefore irrelevant to the problem you are asking about.

Comment: @ChristianM True!

Comment: @Jimenemex I don't think he has enought reputation to place the image inside the question.

Comment: @Jimenemex StackOverflow doesn't allow me to embed images yet.

Comment: @ChristianM Actually, it *is* the PHP code that is causing the problem. Of course OP could fix it with JavaScrip but this is not really a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the default behaviour of your browser:

[image]

Adjust your PHP code, so that `title="Warninggg"` is only there when the condition is true:

```php
<?php 

$title = NULL;

if (isset($_SESSION['emailEmpty']) && $_SESSION['emailEmpty'] == true) {
    $title = 'Warninggg";
}

?>

<input type="email" id="emailPopover" name="email" data-placement="bottom" class="form-control required name" <?php echo $title; ?> data-content="aasd" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="Email">
```